# the post sent by the bot telegram is not deleted for all users

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

I have a function which allows to send a message to all users who clicked the start button.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['Yes'], state=Post.send_post)
async def process_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    for admin in admins:
        if message.from_user.id == admin:
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['send_post'] = message.text
            conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users')
            result = cur.fetchall()
            await state.finish()
            print(result)
            try:
                for z in range(len(result)):
                    print(result[z][0])
                    await dp.bot.send_photo(chat_id=result[z][0], photo=data['photo'], caption=data['CAPTHION'], reply_markup=kb)
                    print(z)
                    test = message.message_id + 1
                    await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=result[z][0], text=f'id поста {test}')
            except BotBlocked:
                print('Пользователь заблокировал бота')
            except ChatNotFound:
                print('Пользователь не запускал бота')
```

Also, there is a function that allows you to delete messages by id. The administrator enters the deleted command, after which the bot asks to enter its id. When the Administrator enters an id, the bot deletes messages through a loop, iterating over the id. But for some reason, it only deletes a post from one user, then it throws an error
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound: Message to delete not found
Please help me I can't figure out why

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['deleted'], state=None)
async def send_id(message: Message):
    for admin in admins:
         if message.from_user.id == admin:
                await Post.Sen_id.set()
                await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=admin, text='Введите ID поста, который нужно удалить.')
    await Post.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=Post.del_mess)
async def deleted_post(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    for admin in admins:
        if message.from_user.id == admin:
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['sen_id'] = message.text
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users')
            result = cur.fetchall()
            #message_ids = int(data['sen_id'])
            for z in range(len(result)):
                print('/////////////deleted/////////////')
                print(result)
                print(z)
                await dp.bot.delete_message(chat_id=result[z][0], message_id=data['sen_id'])
                print('Сообщение удалено')
            #chat_id = message.chat.id

            #await dp.bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message_ids)
            await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=admin, text='пост удален')
        except BotBlocked:
            print('Пользователь заблокировал бота')
        except ChatNotFound:
            print('Пользователь не запускал бота')
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over all the users when deleting a single message? If you try to delete a message with `message_id` in a chat with a different `chat_id`, it's indeed possible that the message will not be found. And if a message with given `message_id` exists in a chat with a different user (because `message_id` is unique only inside single chat, not globally), it may cause unwanted behavior - deleting a message you actually don't want to delete.

Comment: please tell me what should i use to delete message for all users then? @druskacik

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Delete message with given `message_id` from all chats where the message with the `message_id` exists, and ignore those chats where the message does not exist?

Comment: yeap, I need to delete message with given message_id from all chats where the message with the message_id exists. 
For example, for all users who write command start - bot will send a post. And there are cases when this post should be deleted for all users who recieved it. I just don't get should I use for loop or not? @druskacik

Comment: Please see my answer. Please note that when you send a "post" to different users, it may have a different `message_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code that does what you wish for - deleting message with given `message_id` in every chat where that message exist. Later I'll explain why this is actually not a good solution.

The problem is with the placing of the `try-except` block. In your code, if deleting the message fails for a single user, for all users that are past him in the database the deletion will not be even attempted. Solution would be to place the `try-except` block in the for loop.

```py
...
if message.from_user.id == admin:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['sen_id'] = message.text

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users')
result = cur.fetchall()
#message_ids = int(data['sen_id'])
for z in range(len(result)):
    try:
        print('/////////////deleted/////////////')
        print(result)
        print(z)
        await dp.bot.delete_message(chat_id=result[z][0], message_id=data['sen_id'])
        print('Сообщение удалено')
        #chat_id = message.chat.id
        #await dp.bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message_ids)
        await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=admin, text='пост удален')
    except BotBlocked:
        print('Пользователь заблокировал бота')
    except ChatNotFound:
        print('Пользователь не запускал бота')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
...
```

However, after testing this approach, I believe you will realise that there is a problem: if you send a "post" to multiple users, it may have a different `message_id` for different users! So you would have to use a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your option and it works, but the id is still not in the chats of other users. I just don't understand how to rewrite the code so that the /deleted function will delete the post for all users so that it works correctly. @druskacik

Comment: That's because the "post" you send has different `message_id` for different users. What I would do is: everytime you send a post to users, save the post in the database (table `post`), then create table `user_post` where you would save the ids of sent messages - this table would have columns `user_id`, `post_id`, `message_id`. When you delete the post, you delete it by its `id` in the database. If you send all posts to some admin user, `post` table can have some `admin_message_id` column with the `message_id` from the admin chat - you could also delete the posts according to this id.